# Laravel: Uploaded image not showing

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-filesystem

i keep getting `404 image not found` when viewing the uploaded image on my project but the image is there. im using laravel's `asset()` helper to retrieve the image. the url in chrome shows `http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/dU8oaVTAwQyTor86jvDtdGKvE7H3MYkHZuUG60gH.png` and ive already done `php artisan storage:link`. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be question of logical paths. Did you try with localhost:8000? please check the APP_URL in your .env file, you should point your browser to that url

Comment: In addition, if you've linked your storage path, `/images` should reflect an `images` folder under `/storage/app/public/`. Please check if your uploaded png is there.

Comment: its stored on `/storage/app/public/images/`.And updated the APP_URL to `localhost:8000`. still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the asset helper for this, the url generated is wrong.
As you use the public storage, the url is supposed to be like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/dU8oaVTAwQyTor86jvDtdGKvE7H3MYkHZuUG60gH.png
```

Answer (score 0):

but aren't you supposed to access the image through the public folder if you do  `php artisan storage:link`